# Angular 404 page when navigated path does not begin with <base> path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Can't seem to solve this Angular and UI-Router issue. I'm attempting to setup a custom 404 page for my Angular application, but there's an edge case where Angular throws an error rather than handling the route.

My URL is: `http://www.example.com/`

I have a requirement that the application should have a base path, so I use .NET URL Rewrite to redirect all traffic to the correct location:

`http://www.example.com/app/`

To make this work, I use the `<base>` tag in my HTML head section as follows:

```
<base href="/app/">
```

Now all my states work with the `/app/` prefixed.

```
$stateProvider
// https://www.example.com/app/
.state('/', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/Partials/Pages/Home',
  })


  // https://www.example.com/app/login
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: '/Partials/Pages/Login',
  });
```

To make my 404 page work, I define my last state to intercept any unrecognized path:

```
// If no state is matched, load the 404 error
$stateProvider.state('404', {
    url: '*path',
    templateUrl: '/Partials/Pages/PageNotFound',
  });
```

This works almost perfectly. The following URL returns my 404 error:
`https://www.example.com/app/sdfsf`

However, any path that does not begin with my configured base path does not redirect to the 404 error. The following path returns an Angular error:
`https://www.example.com/login`
[image]

Is there a way to handle 404 errors for any URL that does not begin with my base path?

Answer (score 0):

First there is a contradiction in this part of your code:

```
// For any unmatched url, redirect to home
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

// If no state is matched, load the 404 error
$stateProvider.state('404', {
    url: '*path',
    templateUrl: '/Partials/Pages/PageNotFound',
  });
```

What you should do is define your '404' state with the others, then otherwise should redirect to it:

```
$stateProvider
// https://www.example.com/app/
.state('/', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/Partials/Pages/Home',
  })


.state('404', {
    url: '/404',
    templateUrl: '/Partials/404.html',
  });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Comment: First, this still doesn't work for any path not preceded by the the `<base>` path, which is my primary problem. So `https://www.example.com/asdasd` still throws an Angular error and causes application crash. But any path `https://www.example.com/app/asdasd` works well. I've removed the detail about using `.otherwise` because you're right, it's unnecessary.

Comment: you can't access anything that is before the 'base' url because your app doesn't handle that. Can you explain to me how your app is served ? how do you link the domain to your app ?

Comment: ^ This is the answer. Can you add it as a new response, and I will accept it.